# Anybody Know how to send input value into another html page and how to display that value in console

Tags: javascript, html

For this, I tried different way to get that input value but all seems to 
 me complicated. so if you know the quick and easy way to do that please let me know.

Comment: Hey @Sukhwinder, for you to get help please provide code related to what you're working on and a more clear explanation of what you expect that code to do.

Comment: Have you tried *anything at all*?  Where did you get stuck?  If it's "too complicated" then start with something simpler.

Comment: Your question needs a lot more detail if you want to get an answer Sukhwinder. Tell us what exactly your trying to do and what technologies your using. Let us know if your trying to do this on the front or back end and what you've tried already.

Comment: Sounds like you need some persistent storage of some kind and I think the problem is that there isn't much out there in the form of persistent storage that isn't `complicated`. You'll need either a database, to write to a file, or use a service like Google Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the values in the in the URL as query and try to access as `query params` or from URL by iterating it. Then you can display it on console.